# Need to make a dataframe out of two unequal lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have these two lists:

```
l1 = ['ITEM #', 'UNIT PRICE']
l2 = [['123123', '$10.00'], ['456456', '$250.00'], ['789789', '$6.00']]
```

### I want to create a dataframe like:

| ITEM # | UNIT PRICE |
| --- | --- |
| 123123 | $10.00 |
| 456456 | $250.00 |
| 789789 | $6.00 |

Please help with some logical explanation and code! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass both lists to `DataFrame` constructor, for parameters `data` and `columns`:

```
L1 = ['ITEM #', 'UNIT PRICE'] 
L2 = [['123123', '$10.00'], ['456456', '$250.00'], ['789789', '$6.00']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=L2, columns=L1)
print (df)
   ITEM # UNIT PRICE
0  123123     $10.00
1  456456    $250.00
2  789789      $6.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, passing the second list `l2` as data (first parameter by default) and the first list `l1` as column names:

```
l1 = ['ITEM #', 'UNIT PRICE']
l2 = [['123123', '$10.00'], ['456456', '$250.00'], ['789789', '$6.00']]

df = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=l1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   ITEM # UNIT PRICE
0  123123  $10.00   
1  456456  $250.00  
2  789789  $6.00
```

Parameters of the DataFrame constructor:

```
pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=None)
```